# Linked List remove head and return object?

Tags: java, tree, linked-list

I want to remove the head of a linked list and return the object that was removed but I'm not sure if it is removing the head correctly. Here is my code I have, I am using this to build a sorted tree so that is why I need to remove the head of the linked list.

```
// TreeNode class to hold the information of each node.
static class TreeNode{
    int frequency;
    boolean isLeftChild;
    TreeNode parent;
    TreeNode next;

    /**
     * TreeNode class constructor to initialize the variables and also
     * takes a frequency as the parameter.
     * @param f Frequency of a certain character.
     */
    TreeNode(int f){
        frequency = f;
        isLeftChild = true;
        parent = null;
        next = null;
    }
}

// Class used to store information for the linked list.
static class List{
    TreeNode head;
    int numItems; // number of nodes in the list

    List(){
        head = null;
        numItems = 0;
        // initialize head and numItems
    }

    /**
     * Removes the front of the linked list if the head is not null.
     * @return Returns the TreeNode object that was removed.
     */
    TreeNode removeFront(){
        if(head == null){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            numItems--;
            head = head.next;
            return head;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `head = head.removeFirst()` or `head = head.popFirst()`; they both remove the first object and return it.

Comment: Until and unless you write a test and verify it, you will never find out if you have done it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you made mistake here :

```
            head = head.next;
            return head;
```

function should return element next after primary head. Need to do in following way:

```
TreeNode el = head;
head = head.next;
head.prev = null;
return el;
```